# C# class initialization of properties

Tags: c#, .net, initialization

In other modern programming languages it is possible to initialize read-only properties when the parent class has multiple constructors, without duplicating code. But it seems that C# has a rather annoying limitation. For example I have the following C# class:

```
class MyClass
{
    string? str1 { get; init; }
    string? str2 { get; init; }

    public MyClass(string s1)
    {
       this.str1 = s1;
       this.str2 = null;
    }

    public MyClass(string s1, string s2)
    {
       this.str1 = s1;
       this.str2 = s2;
    }
}
```

The constructors can be modified to partially solve the problem as in the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
    string? str1 { get; init; }
    string? str2 { get; init; }

    public MyClass(string s1): this(s1, null) { }

    public MyClass(string s1, string s2)
    {
       this.str1 = s1;
       this.str2 = s2;
    }
}
```

But here's the problem, the call to the first constructor will fail, because I pass null instead of a non null value for s2. I could declare the s2 parameter as nullable in the second constructor, but this is a workaround that doesn't solve the overall problem. The above example is for explanatory purposes only, but I have a real situation where Dependency Injection is needed and I have multiple constructors with common code and several read-only properties that must be initialized when the object is first created and never modified afterwards.
Am I missing something? Other languages have different ways to share initialization code with multiple constructors and cope with the problem that I explained before, but it seems like C# is pretty limited in this respect.
Thanks in advance for any help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Why is that a workaround? `str2` is actually nullable, so it's fine to have a constructor that takes a null string

Comment: Also you don't need to assign `null` to a property that is nullable. `null` is the default-value for `string?` anyway

Comment: suggestion: `public MyClass(string s1, string? s2 = null)`; not sure you need both `init` *and* constructor usage, though - "pick a lane"; other options: `: this(s1, null!)` on the first constructor, or `MyClass(string s1, s2) : this(s1) => str2 = s2;` on the second constructor

Comment: How would you do this in Kotlin/Swift?

Comment: You could also redirect the call to the second ctor to the first one, instead of the other way round: `public MyClass(string s1, string s2) :this(s1) { this.str2 = s2; }`.

Comment: If you rely on dependency injection where you always need results to be non nullable, make the parameter nullable. Then null check, if null initialise that dependency. It is not dirty aslong as you properly check that you do not leave values null that shouldnt be

Comment: What's the purpose of having both an init-property **and** a constructor-overload? As Marc mentioned: chose one instead

Comment: @Sweeper Kotlin has the init block construct together with constructors that gives you more flexibility. Swift uses the init initialization functions that work in a similar way. Not considering that declaring val/let and var members make also things much easier to read and understand in those languages

Comment: Your question would be way clearer, if you'd provided an example in "another language" that has this feature.

Answer (score 5):

There are a ton of options here:

"just do it"

```cs
class MyClass
{
    string str1 { get; }
    string? str2 { get; }

    public MyClass(string s1) : this(s1, null!) { }

    public MyClass(string s1, string s2)
    {
        this.str1 = s1;
        this.str2 = s2;
    }
}
```

"there can be only one"

```cs
class MyClass
{
    string str1 { get; }
    string? str2 { get; }

    public MyClass(string s1, string? s2 = null)
    {
        this.str1 = s1;
        this.str2 = s2;
    }
}
```

"I hate optionals"

```cs
class MyClass
{
    string str1 { get; }
    string? str2 { get; }

    public MyClass(string s1) : this(s1, null) { }

    public MyClass(string s1, string? s2)
    {
        this.str1 = s1;
        this.str2 = s2;
    }
}
```

"do not repeat yourself"

```cs
class MyClass
{
    string str1 { get; }
    string? str2 { get; }

    public MyClass(string s1, string s2) : this(s1) => str2 = s2;
    public MyClass(string s1) => str1 = s1;
}
```

"lazy mode"

```cs
class MyClass(string s1, string? s2 = null)
{
    string str1 => s1;
    string? str2 => s2;
}
```

"let the record state"

```cs
record class MyClass(string str1, string? str2 = null);
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. "just do it" could be a solution :-)... I do not like it because I consider it not exactly very very elegant and clean, it makes code less understandable (my opinion and my opinion only... because I don't like the null! construct, because is counterintuitive compared with VARIABLE! where you assert that is not null)... but it could be the one.

Comment: @SergioB. I added "I hate optionals" - see whether that is cleaner for you

Comment: No, I stick to "Just do it". I have to test its use with the object I'm actually using (it is not a string in my real situation). Thank you anyway, you gave me lots of smart options :-) even If I would've preferred a separate init function (or similar logic) that set the values of the read-only properties at initialization time. Actually mine was more an exercise to find the most elegant solution than a real blocking problem. I simply didn't like to write ugly workarounds.

Comment: I still think calling things that are possible by design "workarounds" is just your perspective of what is ugly rather than an actual ugly way to write.

Comment: @SergioB. Do you want an init-*function*? That you can call in your ctor and that sets all the variables?